# Get element dimension on resize window

Tags: jquery

I have the following code

```
var isSmallScreen = $(".container-inner").width() <= 570;
$(window).resize(function() {
isSmallScreen = $(".container-inner").width() <= 570;
});

console.log(isSmallScreen);
```

When I resize the window I dont get the isSmallScreen.

Im not sure this i sthe way to do it but I want to be able to do stuff with

```
if (isSmallScreen) {
// hide element
}
```

Comment: Have you tride to write `console.log(isSmallScreen);` inside resize event's function?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

when the resize event occurs only the `resize` handle is executed, the console statement after that is not executed, all code that deals with the resize parameters needs to be added in the callback

**Update:**
If you want to do something based on the resize event the solution is to use custom events

```
jQuery(function($){
    var flag;
    $(window).resize(function() {
        var width = $(window).width();
        if(width <= 570){
            if(flag === true || flag == undefined){
                $(window).trigger('smallview', {
                    width: width
                });
                flag = false;
            }
        } else {
            if(flag == false || flag == undefined){
                $(window).trigger('normalview', {
                    width: width
                });
                flag = true;
            }
        }
    }).resize();
})
```

then

```
jQuery(function ($) {
    $(window).on('smallview normalview', function (e) {
        if (e.type == 'smallview') {
            console.log('smallview', 'do something')
        } else {
            console.log('normalview', 'do something')
        }
    });
})
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/GP4QK/)

Answer (score 0):

Only a small change from the other suggestions here.  You can move `isSmallScreen` into a function and call that whenever you need it.  This (in my mind) is just a bit tidier than what you have above...

```
function isSmallScreen() {
    return $(".container-inner").width() <= 570;
}

function smallScreen() {
    // do stuff here because the screen is small
}

$(window).resize(function() {
    if (isSmallScreen()) {
        console.log("isSmallScreen");
        smallScreen();
    }
}).resize();
```

Comment: But i still have to put all smaller screen specific code into that block. I was looking for something I could fire whenever I wanted

Comment: That's easy enough.  I've made another function that is called when the window resizes and is "too small", but you can also call that whenever you like :)

Answer (score 0):

you can use `window.resize()`

like this

```
$(window).resize(function() {
var isScreenSmaller;
if($(".container-inner").width() <= 570){
  isScreenSmaller = true;
}
else
{
 isScreenSmaller = false;
}
alert(isScreenSmaller);
}).resize();
```

Answer (score 0):

you have to use this code i am pretty sure about it [Demo here](http://jsfiddle.net/XDLtA/)

```
$(window).resize(function() {
var isSmallScreen = $(".container-inner").css("width") <= 570;
console.log(isSmallScreen);
})
```